# Basic HTTP Authentication in Gateway API

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, basic-authentication, kubernetes-gateway-api

How does one approach securing an [HTTPRoute](https://gateway-api.sigs.k8s.io/api-types/httproute/) using HTTP Basic Authentication?

From what I understand, Gateway API has no opinion regarding authentication:

> [...] to configure some advanced features like authentication [...], you will **need to rely on the extensions** of the Gateway API ([source](https://gateway-api.sigs.k8s.io/guides/migrating-from-ingress/?h=authentication#approach-to-extensibility))

Another place in the documentation has this to say:

> [...] A Gateway implementation can define **custom resources called Policies** for exposing data plane features like authentication ([source](https://gateway-api.sigs.k8s.io/v1alpha2/guides/migrating-from-ingress/?h=authentication#approach-to-extensibility))

What are some [known Gateway API implementations](https://gateway-api.sigs.k8s.io/implementations/) that implement a policy to support basic HTTP Authentication?

Comment: I think we hope for better support from Gateway API for this. There is an issue about it https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/gateway-api/issues/1494

Answer (score -1):

I have implemented several solutions always with the use of dex and Pomerium.

dex as a federated OpenID Connect provider and Pomerium as an authentication reverse proxy.

Try taking a look at these documentations:

https://dexidp.io/docs/kubernetes/#overview

https://www.pomerium.com/docs/identity-providers

Furthermore, there are Helm Charts provided by the Vendors that are really easy to implement.

Comment: None of these use the Gateway API, hence does not answer the question.